# A generalized LASSO constraint

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lasso, regularization

I want to use LASSO in R but shrinking towards some fixed vector $A$, instead of shrinking towards 0. The desired L1 constraint, given coefficient vector $\beta$, is $||\beta-A||_{1} \leq k$, rather than the standard LASSO constraint, $||\beta||_{1} \leq k$. I haven't been able to find any relevant articles.

For variables, $i$, selected by LASSO, $\beta(i)\ne A(i)$, and, for variables, $j$, NOT selected by LASSO,  $\beta(j) = A(j)$.

For OLS, a solution is to define a shifted parameter vector, $\tilde{\beta}$, and shifted dependent variable, $\tilde{Y}$.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq0}
 \tilde{\beta} = \beta - A ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
   Y = X\beta = X(A+\tilde{\beta}) = XA + X\tilde{\beta} ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq2}
Y - XA = X\tilde{\beta},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq3}
\tilde{Y}=X\tilde{\beta}.
\end{equation}

This shows that LASSO using OLS run with $X$ and $\tilde{Y}$ would give the result $\tilde{\beta}$. The desired $\beta$ is found by adding $A$.

Unfortunately this doesn't help as my models are Poisson and logit. I cannot subtract $XA$ from a count or a Bernoulli rv and have anything sensible. An option would be to treat the $XA$ term in the equation as a constant. In R with lm and glm, the equation can defined with the offset() function which forces a coefficient of 1. This would be a solution but glmnet and other LASSO packages that I've encountered don't have this ability in the equation specification.

I wrote a LASSO implementation but it's slow and lacks important support such as cross validation. I'm hoping someone can point me towards a workable solution that doesn't necessarily have to be LASSO.

Comment: Use $A$ as an offset in your model. Search this site.